# spectral radius and numerical radius of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a complex finite dimensional Hilbert space ($\dim\mathcal{H}=d$). Let $A\in M_d(\mathbb{C})$.

> How can I show without using spectral considerations that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|A^n\|^{\frac{1}{n}}
> \le\displaystyle\sup_{\|x\|=1}|\langle Ax,x\rangle|??
> $$

Thank you for your help!!

This question is a motivation to the following one:

It is well known that the spectral radius of a bounded linear operator $T$ acting on a complex infinite dimensional Hilbert space is given by
$$r(T)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|T^n\|^{\frac{1}{n}}.$$

I want to prove using the above formula (rather than the definition of the spectral radius) that $$r(T)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|T^n\|^{\frac{1}{n}}\le \sup_{\|x\|=1}|\langle Tx.x\rangle|.$$

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}^2$, with the usual Hilbert structure, let $A$ such that for $u=(x_1,x_2)$, $Au=(-x_2,x_1)$. What is $<Au,u>$ ?

Comment: I have assumed that $\mathcal{H}$ is a complex Hilbert space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Michel Crouzeix - Numerical range and functional calculus in Hilbert space](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.crouzeix/publis/Final4.pdf), we see that 
[image]

Using the inequality $2$ with $P(z)=z^n$ we get the desired result.

Comment: This is the link: https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.crouzeix/publis/Final4.pdf

Comment: @daw both links in the comments are broken, too.

Answer (score 3):

Let me denote $\rho:=\lim \|A^n\|^{1/n}$. Then $|\lambda|\le\rho$ for all eigenvalues. Moreover, there is an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ such that $|\lambda|=\rho$. Using the corresponding unit eigenvector, 
$$
\rho \le \sup_{\|x\|=1}| \langle x,Ax\rangle|
$$
follows.

I am not sure what the question is about. For instance, the inequality 
$$
\|A^n\|^{1/n} \le  \sup_{\|x\|=1}| \langle x,Ax\rangle|
$$
is not true for all $n$ in general. To see this, take the nilpotent matrix
$$
A
=\pmatrix{
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots &0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots& 1
\\ 0 & \dots &\dots &0}.
$$
Then $\|A^n\|=1$ for all $n<d$ and $\sup_{\|x\|=1} |\langle x,Ax\rangle|<1$.

Comment: I think the asker does not want to use spectral considerations. I think they are interested in a proof that uses only elementary properties of a Hilbert space and not of its operator algebra. I think this because they have written:  \\ "...I want to prove using the above formula (rather than the definition of the spectral radius) that ....".

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I doesn't  want to use spectral considerations.

Comment: then my answer shows that the inequality only holds in the limit, which excludes the first take on an elementary proof.